# Inconsistent results using 301/2 redirects via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been going somewhat insane over the use of 301 redirects.

I recently turned on "Let's Encrypt" on my hosting cpanel and wish to direct everything over https with no www. I have searched the questions on here and tried various approaches with limited success.

Debugging the situation I have found that only some of the time do my redirects actually work which is not consistent with any of the other questions here.

My htaccess currently has this, taken from an answer elsewhere (note the use of 302 for debugging):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]
```

As an example, when I use a site like [HTTP Status](https://httpstatus.io/) to test 10 instances of each domain, I see that:

- 30% of *http://domain* are subject to 302 redirection
- 90% of *http://www.domain* are subject to 302 redirection
- 0% of *https://domain* are subject to 302 redirection (which is correct)
- 20% of *https://www.domain* are subject to 302 redirection

These numbers do fluctuate between tests, but the concept of inconsistency is proven time and time again.

What am I missing? Why do the redirects only work *some* of the time?

Comment: So if I get it correctly you want to get test results as 100% for redirection?

Comment: I want all http traffic and any https/www traffic to be directed to the https/non-www address, so yes, I would expect 100% redirection, except for the https/non-www address which should be 0% as it’s already the correct destination.